# Save docx render with a specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save a docx that i create. I use the gem `htmltoword`.
The render is a function in the gem I think.

In my controller (but doesn't work) :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.docx do
    @filepath = "#{Rails.root}/app/template/#{@cvmodif.nom}.docx"
    render docx: 'show', filename: 'show.docx'
    send_file(@filepath, :type => 'application/docx', :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
end
```

I have a link. When i click on it, the docx is downloaded corectly. But i want to save it too in a custom path.

```
<%= link_to 'WORD', cv_path(@cvmodif, :format => 'docx') %>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `render` and `send_file` do the same thing: generate a document and send it as an attachment.

If you want to save the document you have to do it manually before sending:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.docx do
    # Generate the document
    my_html = '<html><head></head><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>'
    file_path = "test-#{Time.now.sec}.docx"
    document = Htmltoword::Document.create(my_html)

    # Save it in the custom file 
    File.open(file_path, "wb") do |out|
      out << document
    end 

    # Send the custom file  
    send_file(file_path, :type => 'application/docx', :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
end
```

P.S. According to Htmltodoc source code in the version 0.4.4 there is a function `create_and_save`, but in the currently distributed gem this function is missing. If this scenario is often used in your application I'd recommend you to create a common method for this purposes.

**UPDATE**
Then there is no straightforward solution, because in this case sending of a file is a part of rendering process which is the last step of page's loading and runs deeply inside `Htmltoword`.

The most correct solution is to make this a Htmltoword's feature. (Create feature request or even implement it by yourself).

But for the moment you can take renderer of *.docx files from the library and add minimal changes to achieve your goals.

Create a file `RailsApp/config/initializers/application_controller.rb`.
Add this code of docx renderer taken from [github](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword/blob/master/lib/htmltoword/action_controller.rb)

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :docx do |filename, options|
  formats[0] = :docx unless formats.include?(:docx) || Rails.version < '3.2'

  # This is ugly and should be solved with regular file utils
  if options[:template] == action_name
    if filename =~ %r{^([^\/]+)/(.+)$}
      options[:prefixes] ||= []
      options[:prefixes].unshift $1
      options[:template] = $2
    else
      options[:template] = filename
    end
  end

  # disposition / filename
  disposition = options.delete(:disposition) || 'attachment'
  if file_name = options.delete(:filename)
    file_name += '.docx' unless file_name =~ /\.docx$/
  else
    file_name = "#{filename.gsub(/^.*\//, '')}.docx"
  end

  # other properties
  save_to = options.delete(:save_to)
  word_template = options.delete(:word_template) || nil
  extras = options.delete(:extras) || false

  # content will come from property content unless not specified
  # then it will look for a template.
  content = options.delete(:content) || render_to_string(options)
  document = Htmltoword::Document.create(content, word_template, extras)
  File.open(save_to, "wb") { |out| out << document } if save_to 
  send_data document, filename: file_name, type: Mime::DOCX, disposition: disposition
end
```

If you compare this file to the source one you'll find that I've added `save_to` option and when this option is set, renderer saves a document to the given location.

Usage in the controller:

```
format.docx do
  render docx: 'my_view', filename: 'my_file.docx', save_to: "test-#{Time.now.sec}.docx"
end
```

Comment: Ok but I Don't have any raw html. I have a `show.docx.erb` I put my html inside

Comment: thanks for your help but that doesn't work. I have no error but there is no file created. Maybe is beacause i'm on windows. I have already the 0.4.4

Comment: I tested this solution on Windows as well. Are you sure that your renderer is called? Did you run this code under debugger? Did File.open create the file?

Comment: The file is not created. In order to execute the code i call the show view of where i put the code in my controller. I have rails 4.2.1. Moreover I have a download link that work well I can download my word created by `htmltoword` correctly. `<%= link_to 'WORD', cv_path(@cvmodif, :format => 'docx') %>`

Comment: I didn't mention, but you have to restart Rails server after you change something in 'config/initializers' section. Did you restart it?

Comment: That work ! You are my hero ! :) I just forget to restart my server :/